# A sed command to swap first and last character of each line

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, text-processing

I want to write a one liner sed command to swap first and last character of every line of file. The below shown command is not working

```
 sed 's/\(.\)\(.+\)\(.\)/\3\2\1/' input.txt
```

I even tried adding start of line and end of line characters

```
 sed 's/^\(.\)\(.+\)\(.\)$/\3\2\1/' input.txt
```

It doesn't seem to match anything in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `+`,

```
sed 's/^\(.\)\(.\+\)\(.\)$/\3\2\1/' input.txt
```

Comment: Or use `sed -r` and drop the escaping slashes from the `(` and `)` characters.

Comment: `-r` option won't be supported on some sed's.

Comment: Absolutely true (re: portability of `-r) but it is a valid alternative nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -E 's/(.)(.+)(.)/\3\2\1/' input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to try some other, here is a `gnu awk` version

```
awk '{a=$1;$1=$NF;$NF=a}1' FS= OFS= input.txt
```

This sets `a` to the first character, then sets first to last and last to `a`
It needs `gnu awk`, since settings `FS` to nothing is not in standard `awk`

Comment: okay so, if we give nothing as FS and OFS then it considers each character as a field? and what is the 1 doing? new line?

Comment: @dharakk The `1` is some true, and some true does the default action `print the line` so `1`=`{print $0}`

Answer (score 1):

This works portable:

```
abcd | sed 's/^\(.\)\(.*\)\(.\)$/\3\2\1/'
```

you can use the `.*`. Prints

```
dbca
```

also works with the `ad` too, like

```
echo ad | sed 's/^\(.\)\(.*\)\(.\)$/\3\2\1/'
```

prints

```
da
```

The `.+` isn't known for every `sed` e.g. for example it didn't work on OS X. Therefore I recommending to use `.*` or simulating the `.+` with `..*`, like

```
echo ad | sed 's/^\(.\)\(..*\)\(.\)$/\3\2\1/'
```

prints

```
ad #not swaps
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'are' | sed 's/\(.\)\(.*\)\(.\)/\3\2\1/'
```

- No need of `^` nor `$` becasue sed take the biggest possible by default (so the whole line)
- use `*` instead of `+` because with the `+` you need at least a 3 char line to works where a 2 char line still should swap start and end.